# Django/Jython ImproperlyConfigured error

Tags: django, jython

As specified in the tutorial (http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonDjango.html), I am using doj.backends.zxjdbc.postgresql as Django's DB engine. However, when I do

```
jython manage.py syncdb
```

I get an ImproperlyConfigured error, stating that doj.backends.zxjdbc.postgresql is not an available backend and that no module named postgresql exists. Strangely, if I enter the Jython shell, I can do

```
import doj.backends.zxjdbc.postgresql
```

without any error messages.

Ideas on what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: django-jython is out of date. 1.4 is not currently supported, so there is no solution to this issue other than to revert to a supported version of django.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems like django-jython is not seeing much/any active development anymore...

However, I have found that development versions available at the Google code repository below do work in Django 1.5 (and I assume they may work with 1.4 too, if you pick the right version):
https://code.google.com/p/django-jython/source/list

In particular, I have found that this dev version works with Django 1.5:
https://code.google.com/p/django-jython/source/detail?r=c4a0dd949a6d86a4baf8d1bed3b1926fa5318e87